# add-migration causing Could not load assembly ''. Ensure it is referenced by the startup project ''

Tags: asp.net, .net-core, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations

When I want to use add-migration on .Net core I receive this error

```
PM> add-migration AuthenticationDB
Build started...
Build succeeded.
Could not load assembly ''. Ensure it is referenced by the startup project ''.
```

What does the error message mean? How I can fix it?

This my project .csproj

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.All" Version="2.0.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="3.1.9" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Analyzers" Version="3.1.9" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="3.1.9" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="3.1.9" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

Answer (score 3):

If you only have one project in your solution, make sure that your **Package Manager Console** has the repository project selected in the drop down at the top.

If you have multiple projects in your solution then you need to reference a UI project (web. console, winforms etc) using the `-s` flag and a reference to your repository project with the `-p` flag.

For example;

`Add-Migration MyMigrationMessage -s MySolution.MyWebProject -p MySolution.MyDataProject`

Comment: I only have one project in my solution and already selected in the drop down at the top, but it still not working

Comment: Could  you try specifying just your project name `Add-Migration MyMigrationMessage -p MySolution.MyDataProject`

Comment: Also run `Get-Package` - which version of entity framework are you using?